# Mule 4 : Transform Message does not show its related properties for editing in studio

Tags: mule4

Issue : When I drag and drop the Transform message component in **Anypoint Studio v7.4.2** , I am not able to see the properties to edit it.
The issue started occurring suddenly when I was debugging an application in Studio.
It said :

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Class org.mule.tooling.ui.dfl.contribution.editor.script.output.OutputPreviewController$1 does not implement the requested interface com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback
```

And since then I have tried to

- close and reopen project,
- reimport project in Anypoint Studio
- restarted studio and the Windows system

but nothing is working.

Attached is the screenshot. Can someone please help?
[image: Transform message issues]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resetting perspective. Windows -> perspective -> Reset Perspective or switch workspace . If that fails you can always reinstalling Studio.

Comment: I tried resetting the perspective. I get the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: switch workspace. If that doesn't do it i guess your only option is reinstalling Studio

Comment: reinstalled Studios to resolve the issue.